# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'desktop-khcvncn\sql;database'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, c#-4.0

[image]

```
 public class CarContext:DbContext
    {
        //we are selecting the which database
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"DESKTOP-KHCVNCN\SQL;Database=Cars;Trusted_Connection=true");
        }
        //which object in sql server match which object in project we are doint it
        public DbSet<Car> CarsInformations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

ı think that ı can not connect the sql server that's why it is giving error

but everthings is okay what can ı do solve for this problem?

Comment: Why do you believe you can just put the server name at the start of the connection string without specifying what it is? I'd expect `Server=DESKTOP-KHCVNCN\SQL` or similar... See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring

Comment: @Murat OZ, Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official document:[Configuring the database provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#configuring-the-database-provider)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test");
    }
}
```

You should use connectionString as the parameter of UseSqlServer, which you can find in the properties of cars in your picture-2.

[image]